# Extracting the value of one cell conditionning on the value of another column - Pandas / Python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame, `df`, like this:

```
    Rank    User
0   1690    samberman1212
1   1690    khogan3131
2   1690    narguero
3   1690    Awesemo
4   1690    Awesemo
5   1690    cptnspaulding
6   1690    Fluke7634
7   1690    giantsquid
8   1690    vidthekid22
9   1690    I_Slewfoot_U
10  1690    Mirage88
11  1690    Mirage88
12  1690    Mirage88
13  1690    Testosterown
14  1715    Anonymous
15  1715    Anonymous
```

I want to use the number of times each user is in `df`.
So, I created a new data frame, `multiple` :

```
multiple=users_df.groupby("User").count()
print(multiple) 

             Rank
User    
Anonymous     2
Awesemo       2
Fluke7634     1
I_Slewfoot_U  1
Mirage88      3
Testosterown  1
cptnspaulding 1
giantsquid    1
khogan3131    1
narguero      1
samberman1212 1
vidthekid22   1
```

Finally, I would like to extract the frequency count to assign it to a variable, `count_IP` :

```
 for i, row in users_df.iterrows():
                    rank = row['Rank']
                    user = row['User']

                    count_IP= ???
```

Thus, I would like to be able to look in `multiple` for the count value for the user (`user`) in the loop at that moment... I try :

```
multiple.query('User==user')['Rank']
#AND 
multiple[multiple["User"]==user]["Rank"]
```

But, both did not work. It looks like the user column, the variable on which the group by was done, is not callable. Because when I ask for the column names:

```
   list(multiple.columns.values)
    ['Rank']
```

How can I solve this ?

Update:

Instead of the frequency count, let say I want to obtain :

```
     Rank       User               order of appearance
0   1690    samberman1212                  1
1   1690    khogan3131                     1
2   1690    narguero                       1
3   1690    Awesemo                        1
4   1690    Awesemo                        2
5   1690    cptnspaulding                  1
6   1690    Fluke7634                      1
7   1690    giantsquid                     1
8   1690    vidthekid22                    1
9   1690    I_Slewfoot_U                   1
10  1690    Mirage88                       1
11  1690    Mirage88                       2
12  1690    Mirage88                       3
13  1690    Testosterown                   1
14  1715    Anonymous                      1
15  1715    Anonymous                      2
```

UPDATE#2:

I am trying on a data frame with more anonymous.

```
ank User    order of appearence
0   1   boggslite   1
1   2   dokcash 1
2   3   loumister35 1
3   4   drhass  1
4   5   onem4nwolfpack  1
5   6   felder15    1
6   7   TwoStix 1
7   8   Mwise120    1
8   9   sdchickens  1
9   10  tastefultides   1
10  11  bric75  1
11  12  ycmmat  1
12  13  tastefultides   1
13  14  mpgoldberg16    1
14  14  mpgoldberg16    2
15  16  Cicima6709  1
16  17  LSUTom123   1
17  18  bunglerprime    1
18  18  Testosterown    1
19  20  dfsteams    1
20  20  yankeesfan2 1
21  22  tfinnerty   1
22  23  bellmar21   1
23  24  Awesemo 1
24  25  shocky26    1
25  25  tastefultides   1
26  27  Thanks4DaChedda 1
27  28  isupol  1
28  28  jwestphal708    1
29  30  giantsquid  1
30  31  boggslite   1
31  32  Thanks4DaChedda 1
32  33  dre87   1
33  33  BlarneyBoys 1
34  33  bric75  1
35  36  ezellmt 1
36  36  Cicima6709  1
37  38  ivanage 1
38  38  Thanks4DaChedda 1
39  40  nevs2904    1
40  41  gridironguru999 1
41  42  Anonymous   1
42  43  Anonymous   1
43  44  Anonymous   1
44  45  Anonymous   1
45  45  Anonymous   2
46  47  Anonymous   1
47  48  Anonymous   1
48  49  Anonymous   1
49  50  Anonymous   1
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Can you please explain? Preferably with expected result.

Comment: Let say, user= Mirage88 . I simply want count_IP to equal 3. My for loop is going through all row of `df`, and there is a variable user that takes the value of the name of the user of that row. So, I want to extract the count from `multiple` and assign it to count_IP. Is it clearer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you want to `df.groupby()` with [`transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html)

```
df['count_IP']=df.groupby('User').transform('count')
print(df)

    Rank           User  count_IP
0   1690  samberman1212         1
1   1690     khogan3131         1
2   1690       narguero         1
3   1690        Awesemo         2
4   1690        Awesemo         2
5   1690  cptnspaulding         1
6   1690      Fluke7634         1
7   1690     giantsquid         1
8   1690    vidthekid22         1
9   1690   I_Slewfoot_U         1
10  1690       Mirage88         3
11  1690       Mirage88         3
12  1690       Mirage88         3
13  1690   Testosterown         1
14  1715      Anonymous         2
15  1715      Anonymous         2
```

*You can then perform `df=df.drop_duplicates()` if you want the duplicate values removed.*

**EDIT for order of appearence :**

```
df['order of appearence']=df.groupby('User')['User'].transform(lambda x : x.duplicated().cumsum().add(1)) 
print(df)

    Rank           User  order of appearence
0   1690  samberman1212                    1
1   1690     khogan3131                    1
2   1690       narguero                    1
3   1690        Awesemo                    1
4   1690        Awesemo                    2
5   1690  cptnspaulding                    1
6   1690      Fluke7634                    1
7   1690     giantsquid                    1
8   1690    vidthekid22                    1
9   1690   I_Slewfoot_U                    1
10  1690       Mirage88                    1
11  1690       Mirage88                    2
12  1690       Mirage88                    3
13  1690   Testosterown                    1
14  1715      Anonymous                    1
15  1715      Anonymous                    2
```

Comment: Instead of the frequency count, will it be possible to have the order of appearance?

Comment: Everything works fine, except for `Anonymous` user that did not have the same ranking. It starts the order of appearance to 1 for `Anonymous` that ranked differently. I would like to increase the number of appearances considering all `Anonymous`.

Comment: Not working, the output of `df["order of appereance"]` is the same.

Comment: Its working for me did you add another user named `Anonymous` and a different rank and check ? `df["order of appereance"]=df.groupby(['User','Rank'])['User'].transform(lambda x : x.duplicated().cumsum().add(1))` this is working for me. Add 1716 as anonymous and check

Comment: Yes, I am trying on a different dataframe with more anonymous. I will put it in the initial question on the update section if you could try on your side if it is working, thanks a lot

Comment: It is the second column.

Comment: @Jagr i am now confused, you wanted the order per user per rank ryt? Thats exactly what you are getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187626/discussion-between-jagr-and-anky-91).